# Have they Changed the Power of the Honey Badger

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

It seems that the Honey Badger is not a potent as it was before the latest update to COD Ghosts. Was this due to a rebalance update to the game?

Comment: Knowing nothing of Call of Duty, I can only assume this is a shoulder mounted Honey Badger launcher. Which, frankly, makes me want to play the game.

Comment: @DavidYell Almost, currently it feels as powerful as that would be, but not quite I'm afraid :)

Comment: Not sure why this has been down voted. Would someone care to elaborate? Is this not a Exchange site for gaming questions? I will set my real life Honey Badger on the person who downvoted with impunity!

Comment: @Lyrical You can run ahead of me then into the swarm of angry Honey Badgers.

Comment: @Killercam Your question sounds opinionated, so thus there are bound to be some downvotes because it looks to only be answered by opinions. However, this is due to some not playing the new Ghosts or having never played CoD. Read nothing into it, just look to how you can format your question into looking for facts.

Comment: People should not be down voting because they have never played COD Ghosts. In addition (prior to your edit) the question was fine and was not ambiguous/opinionated what-so-ever. Regardless, thanks for your time...

Comment: Not a definitive answer, but Symthic has recently added Ghosts weapon stats. The [Honey Badger](http://symthic.com/cod-ghosts-weapon-info?w=Honey_Badger) has only been updated once so far and that was in the initial release (4th Nov). So far nothing indicates that the gun stats have changed. I'm not sure if they keep older stat revisions, so maybe make a note of the significant stats and keep checking back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its anything like Black Ops 2, they release balance patches on a regular basis, but do not require a game update anymore. This makes it difficult to tell when it happens, but if you follow them on websites they might release when they do a balance patch.

Comment: +1 thanks. But are you sure they don't need to formally patch. How else would they update the software?

Comment: Black Ops 2 and Mw3 got weapon stats from the server. I cant find the article for it now since every google search about CoD now is all ghosts. I would geuss Ghost works the same way. Google is also showing results for a 1.03 patch recently pushed, but no official notes have been released: http://www.charlieintel.com/2013/11/09/new-patch-v-1-03-for-ghosts-released-for-ps3/
So if you didnt get a game update.. then its probably working the same way as the other titles.